# Getting last day of current month 

Tags: groovy

In Groovy, how can I find the last day of the current month?

Thanks for your sage advice and better wisdom.

Comment: I think I found answer to the weekday by using Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK

Comment: Solved weekday by using def asd = new Date().format('EEEE') but it's still in my native language

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, as you commented, Calendar.FIELD is probably your best friend (though groovy's TimeCategory also has neat tricks).

Here's how i made for the last day of the current month:

```
Calendar.with {
    println instance.getActualMaximum( DATE )
}
```

I didn't understood what you meant by "break out the current weekday if I'm looping through a month". Perhaps getting the weekday for each month?

```
Calendar.with {
    (JANUARY..DECEMBER).each { month ->
        def cal = instance
        cal[MONTH] = month
        println cal[DAY_OF_WEEK]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, what I meant was to write out "sunday" etc. But I solved that one simply by formatting the date, but if you have a better way of solving it please let me know. Also, one more thing, it writes out "söndag" which is the swedish word of "sunday". How may I change the locale?

Thanks!

Comment: Using DateFormatSymbols with a specific Locale is a solution:
`import java.text.*;
def locale = Locale.availableLocales.find { it.language=="es" };
def dfs = new DateFormatSymbols(locale);
def cal = Calendar.instance;
println dfs.weekdays[ cal[ Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK ] ]`